# Securing a REST application in SpringBoot and accessing it from a Rest Client

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security, spring-boot

I am pretty new to Springboot. I have developed a rest server but I was wondering how to perform Basic authentication from a client and how to configure the spring boot server to authenticate request. The tutorials I saw online didn't include a restful client. Would be great if you can show some code including both the client request and server authentication process with springboot rest.

Comment: What http client are you using?

Comment: I use the Jersey client.

Comment: But any java client will do for my specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the client side since you are using Jersey Client you need to do something like the following:

```
Client c = Client.create();
c.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(user, password));
```

One the server side you need to enable Spring Security and set Basic Authentication for it which would look something like the following (this is the simplest possible case).

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class RootConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
{
auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
    .withUser("tester").password("passwd").roles("USER");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http
     .authorizeUrls()
         .anyRequest().authenticated()
         .and()
     .httpBasic();       
  }
}
```

Comment: Using Spring Boot so no need for any of that configuration (unless you really want it). The default password is printed on the console on startup.

Comment: @DaveSyer Thanks for that info! That is a feature that had evaded my attention since the times I needed security I needed to do some more manual configuration. Maybe you should add your comment as answer for everyone to easily see

Comment: @DaveSyer Also, it might be a good idea for you fine people at Pivotal to update the following guide https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/, to reflect the ability of Boot to autoconfigure security

Comment: My comment doesn't really answer the question, and the Spring Boot docs are pretty clear about [how to secure a basic application](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security). If you want to change the guide, it has a github issue tracker. It might indeed make sense to give it an extra step that just used the Boot defaults.

Comment: Thanks, @geoand for the tip. I found this might help too https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-secure